# Getting error in Talend job with tHiveConnection component

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, etl, talend

I am getting this error while executing the talend job with tHiveConnection.

I am using Java 1.7, Hadoop 2.2 & talend open studio for big data 6.0

Please help me in identify this error.

Please find below the error details

```
Starting job CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS at 09:15 09/08/2015.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3662
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tHiveConnection_1
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at packt_big_data.ch04_01_hive_processing_hash_tags_0_1.CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS.tHiveConnection_1Process(CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS.java:689)
    at packt_big_data.ch04_01_hive_processing_hash_tags_0_1.CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS.runJobInTOS(CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS.java:2084)
    at packt_big_data.ch04_01_hive_processing_hash_tags_0_1.CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS.main(CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS.java:1833)
[statistics] disconnected
Job CH04_01_HIVE_PROCESSING_HASH_TAGS ended at 09:15 09/08/2015. [exit code=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` was used to connect to the original HiveServer.

With HiveServer2 use `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` -- and reading some [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-ConnectionURLs) could do no harm, especially the comment that reads *"we need the following **jars** in the **classpath**"*